# Проблема с парсингом

Tags: python

У меня возникла проблема с парсингом тега`<pre`
Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20"


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r.text)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('pre', class_='fig')
    print(items)


def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
    print("Парсинг")
    get_content(html.text)

else:
    print("Сайт не дает подключится")


parse()
```

Буду рад за вашу помощь

Comment: я так понимаю не находит этот тег. Вероятно страница генерится JS. И в исходнике нет этих данных. Но Вы их видите в отладчике браузера. Вам нужно использовать либо  request-html либо через silenium Либо искать и посылать POST запрос на получение этих данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только скачать нужно chromedriver и положить в папку с программой.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('http://www.patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20')
html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
with open('page.html', 'w+',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
    f.close()
driver.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("page.html",encoding='utf-8'), "html.parser")
items = soup.findAll('pre',class_ = 'fig')
print(items)

Результат
[<pre class="fig" contenteditable="true" id="taag_output_text" style="float:left;">___________                        _________                      __  .__    .__
\__    ___/__.__.______   ____    /   _____/ ____   _____   _____/  |_|  |__ |__| ____    ____
  |    | &lt;   |  |\____ \_/ __ \   \_____  \ /  _ \ /     \_/ __ \   __\  |  \|  |/    \  / ___\
  |    |  \___  ||  |_&gt; &gt;  ___/   /        (  &lt;_&gt; )  Y Y  \  ___/|  | |   Y  \  |   |  \/ /_/  &gt;
  |____|  / ____||   __/ \___  &gt; /_______  /\____/|__|_|  /\___  &gt;__| |___|  /__|___|  /\___  /
          \/     |__|        \/          \/             \/     \/          \/        \//_____/   </pre>]
PS D:\Python\classtest>
```